# Setup DNS records for SMTP send-only server

Tags: linux, smtp, email-server, spf, dns-zone

I have website on hosting with domain exmpl.com.
I have DNS record for exmpl.com:

**exmpl.com MX(10) mail.exmpl.com 

mail.exmpl.com A XX.XX.XX.XX 

exmpl.com TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +a:hosting.server ~all**

All incoming mail recived by hosting server. 
Now all mail work over hosting server. I want to create SMTP server to send-only mail. I use Postfix.
And create DNS record for exmpl.com:
**smtp.exmpl.com A XX.XX.XX.XX  

smtp._domainkey.exmpl.com TXT DKIM key**

I have PTR on smtp.exmpl.com. How to setup spf record to send mail. 
Example: i want to send mail from user1@exmpl.com to user2@gmail.com, but use my smtp server smtp.exmpl.com. 
Do i need to create subdomain on hosting, smtp.exmpl.com and setup spf record for it? if yes, how to use this record in spf record of exmpl.com?
PS: SMTP server on Ubuntu 18 (This **only-send** SMTP server)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `a:smtp.exmpl.com` to your SPF DNS record for `exmpl.com`. You don't need `+` before `a`, `mx`, they are assumed by default.

You need to make sure that your `PTR` record matches forward resolution. If your `postfix` server is running on the host with IP `192.168.0.1` then `smtp.exmpl.com` should have `A` record `192.168.0.1` and `PTR` record for `192.168.0.1` should return `smtp.exmpl.com`. Your server should send `smtp.exmpl.com` as `HELO`.